# How to inject code in .ipa file

Tags: ios, ipa, word-wrap, code-injection

Any one have an idea how to inject code and files in .ipa file like app wrapping feature of Good dynamics (Containerizing via App Wrapping).

http://www1.good.com/secure-mobility-solution/mobile-application-containerization/wrapping-or-coding.html

I have searched a lot but still not found any clue so please let me know any one having the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can. Since the IPA contains the app which singed and any changes to it will make the signature invalid.

Comment: If you click on above link of Good dynamics and see the topic 'Containerizing via App Wrapping' then you can get the idea. They are injecting their own frameworks and code into .ipa by subimmiting .ipa and certificate.

Comment: Agreed, it is probably feasible technically. Such a wrapper will likely need to also analyse code and intercept iOS API calls.